# How to put slider to max position when min and max values are the same?

Tags: html

I have an HTML input element as below:

```html
<input type="range" min=10 max=10 value=10>
```

The thing is that I want this slider thumb to be at the end of track when min and max are equal. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Hi Arpit, please attach the UI you want to achieve as I can see the point you are mentioning isn't right as your min and max value can not be the same.

Comment: @ManikKumar According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max) they can be the same: "This value must be greater than **or equal** to the value of the min attribute."

Comment: @NullDev it is very clear that if you are going to put min, max and value like this which is equals to 10 then you can't get the expected behaviour